# Changing the label of Lightning Quick Action closing button

Tags: aura, quickaction

When implementing a lightning quick action creating an aura component that implements `force:lightningQuickAction`, it comes by default with a "Cancel" Button, which I would like to rename as "OK" or Done without implementing `force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader`?

Comment: Are you talking about `force:lightningQuickAction`? Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to build the quick action using `force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader`.

If you want to stick to the `force:lightningQuickAction` you can try to add the following code as pointed out in this idea: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003Sq6QAE:

```
 ({
afterRender: function (component, helper) {

    this.superAfterRender();
    var elCompFooter = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-footer");
        if (elCompFooter.length == 1) {
            var elCancelButton = elCompFooter[0].getElementsByClassName("cuf-publisherCancelButton uiButton");

            if (elCancelButton.length == 1 && !elCancelButton[0].hasOwnProperty('onclick')) {
                elCancelButton[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].textContent = $A.get("$Label.c.BP_Close_Window");
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks, how do you wire this? do you need to place in the renderer.js?